# How to create app store build from xcode 4.2?

Tags: build, app-store, xcode4.2

I have developed the universal app using xcode 4.2. It is the time to upload the app to iTunes connect(Submit to App Store). Last time i have submitted and created app store build from xcode 3.2.5. Now, i really confused that to create an app store build from XCode 4.2. Please help me to get an app store build from XCode 4.2. I need to submit app to App store today itself. Please help me. Thanks in advance. How to get the .app file and how to upload the .app file through Application Loader application? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the answer for my own questions. I have used Apple document to submit my application to app store. This link may very useful for you. Please keep it safe. `http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode4.2 you need to do following steps;
1)Set iOS Device as platform
2)Go to Product->Archive
3)xcode organiser get open, select your archive and select Submit/Share as per your requirment.